# Javascript code for automatically checking a checkbox based on clicking a field

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a digital signature box on my form (in Acrobat) and would like a checkbox to be automatcally checked, once a user clicks on this signature box in order to sign the form. Can someone please help with the javascript coding required for this, thanks.

Comment: just select the checkbox by id and get the value

Comment: What did you try, where is your code?

Comment: I dont actually have any code for this as i am new to coding with javascript. So it would be very helpful of someone could write a generic piece of coding i could adjust to my form in order for it to work. Thank you